# ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "Parcelles_class.OBJECTID" = 1 OR "output_table1.src_OBJECTID" = 1 Failed to execute (Select)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000358, error-001143

I'm executing this code. I don't know if i'm missing something,

I'm using Arcpy, Python, Arcgis 10.1

```
whereclause1 = '"Parcelles_class.OBJECTID" = 1'
whereclause2 = '"output_table1.src_OBJECTID" = 1'
arcpy.Select_analysis("Join_Output_3","target_neighbor_parcel",whereclause1 + " OR " + whereclause2)
```

I got this error while i'm executing it on PYTHON window:

> ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.

And this while i execute it in IDLE :

> ERROR 000358: Expression non valide Parcelles_class.OBJECTID = 1 OR
>   output_table1.src_OBJECTID = 1 Ã‰chec de lâ€™exÃ©cution de (Select).

Comment: Now i get this Error : ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Expression non valide "Parcelles_class.OBJECTID" = 1AND"output_table1.src_OBJECTID" = 1
Ã‰chec de lâ€™exÃ©cution de (Select).

Answer (score 1):

you should put some spaces before and after the AND when you concatenate. Like this:

```
 + " AND " +
```

also you could try and add the parentheses

```
"(" + whereclause1 + ") OR (" + whereclause2 + ")"
```

Comment: I did it ! and they give me now this : Background server threw an exception. Then the operation it stopted

Comment: does each whereclause work independently ?

Comment: radouxju Yes it does !

Comment: and what if you add parentheses around each clause?

Comment: it gives the same error: ERROR 000358: Expression non valide "Parcelles_class.OBJECTID" = 1 OR "output_table1.src_OBJECTID" = 1
Ã‰chec de lâ€™exÃ©cution de (Select)

Comment: plz radouxju reread the question, beacause i made some changes !

Comment: for error 1143, try disabling background processes in ArcGIS. This can be done via the Geoprocessing Options dialog box. For the error 358 in IDLE,  you "lost" your " " in the process. try using """ "field" = 1 """ instead, but I believe that you create your whereclause in the process and that your sample does not exactly reflect what you are doing.

Comment: getting the same erroe : ERROR 000358
for the secong error when i disabled the backround processes, Arcamp blocked and stoped working !